# Swift: Add prefix (string) into a string

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, prefix

I'm looking for a `String` function that adds prefix string into an existing string.

The problem I've is: Sometimes, I get a URL string from web service response without keyword ***http:***.

The general form of URL (URL string) should be: http://www.testhost.com/pathToImage/testimage.png

But sometimes I get `//www.testhost.com/pathToImage/testimage.png` from web service.

Now, I know that I can check, whether prefix `http:` is there in a string or not, but if there isn't then I need to add prefix into an existing URL string.

Is there any String (or substring or string manipulation) function that adds prefix into my URL string?

I tried into Apple document: [String](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) but couldn't find any help.

An alternate way I have is a concatenation of string.

Here is my code:

```
var imageURLString = "//www.testhost.com/pathToImage/testimage.png"

if !imageURLString.hasPrefix("http:") {
   imageURLString = "http:\(imageURLString)"  // or  "http:"+ imageURLString
}
print(imageURLString)
```

But is there any standard way or iOS String default function that I can use here?

Comment: How is `let url = "http://" + "testhost.com/..."` not native?

Comment: `URL.init(string: imageURLString, relativeTo: URL.init(string:"http://"))` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth - You may be right, that is current alternate option for me, but its general string manipulation operation. While there is `hasPrefix` then i think there should be something like `addPrefix`

Comment: Well write your own extension that does exactly that. I'm guessing it doesn't exist b/c doing `func add(prefix: String) { self = prefix + self }` seems redundant.

Comment: @Larme - I have no idea how your trick would work (I mean, i've never seen such kind of code) but let me try it.

Comment: @Larme: Why don't you post that as an answer? It is a simple and correct solution for the problem. (Just omit the unnecessary `.init` :)

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be working with "www.testhost.com/pathToImage/testimage3.png", so...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative is `URLComponents`. This works with or without `http`

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "//www.testhost.com/pathToImage/testimage.png")!
if urlComponents.scheme == nil { urlComponents.scheme = "http" }
let imageURLString = urlComponents.url!.absoluteString
```

Comment: Was going to suggest something similar :) – Perhaps check `if urlComponents.scheme == nil ...` so that an existing scheme is preserved.

Answer (score 9):

If `"http:" + "example.com"` doesn't suit you, you could write your own extension that does this:

```
extension String {
    mutating func add(prefix: String) {
        self = prefix + self
    }
}
```

...or make it test the string before adding the prefix, to add it only if it doesn't exist yet:

```
extension String {
    /**
      Adds a given prefix to self, if the prefix itself, or another required prefix does not yet exist in self.  
      Omit `requiredPrefix` to check for the prefix itself.
    */
    mutating func addPrefixIfNeeded(_ prefix: String, requiredPrefix: String? = nil) {
        guard !self.hasPrefix(requiredPrefix ?? prefix) else { return }
        self = prefix + self
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// method 1
url.add(prefix: "http:")
// method 2: adds 'http:', if 'http:' is not a prefix
url.addPrefixIfNeeded("http:")
// method 2.2: adds 'http:', if 'http' is not a prefix (note the missing colon which includes to detection of 'https:'
url.addPrefixIfNeeded("http:", requiredPrefix: "http")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in but you could do this in one line with a conditional assignment. See the following:
`imageURLString = imageURLString.hasPrefix("http:") ? imageURLString : ("http:" + imageURLString)`

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this thread should be retitled to dealing more with URL String Manipulation. To return to prefixing Strings, you don't have to do this using an extension, but to use a Higher Order function (for collections)

#### Collections of Strings

```
let prefix = "Mr."
self.dataSource = myMaleFriends.map({ (friend) -> String in
    return prefix + " " + friend
})
```

#### For prefixing a single word

```
var name = "Anderson"

name = name.withMutableCharacters({ (name) -> String in
    return "Mr. " + name
})
```